# Is every integer greater than 1 the sum of a palindrome and a prime?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, palindromes

Helfgott proved that any odd number greater than 5 is the sum of three primes. Cilleruelo and Luca proved that every positive integer is the sum of three palindromes.

Is every integer greater than 1 the sum of a prime and a nonnegative palindrome (i.e. a number whose canonical base-10 expansion is a palindrome)?

Comment: 2 isn't, if I understand the question correctly...

Comment: @Douglas Ulrich: Actually, 2 = 2+0 (a prime +  a palindrome)...

Comment: Ah, I was thinking positive, not nonnegative... sorry

Comment: Bernardo, Could you say up to which number you have tested?

Comment: Of course it should be true (at least for large integers), since there are plenty of palindromes (and also plenty of primes).  However, we don't know how to solve binary problems (e.g. twin primes, binary Goldbach etc), and this problem looks similarly intractable.  It is conceivable that one might be able to do something for "slightly dirty" palindromes (that is a bounded number of digits may not match up, but the number is mostly palindromic).  This would of course need serious work, but an analog is Linnik's theorem on sums of two primes and boundedly many powers of $2$.

Comment: Perhaps the sequence 9999, 999999, 99999999, 9999999999 contains a counterexample.  Since there are no palindromic primes with an even number of digits, we need a prime with an even number of digits which begins with a block of nines followed by a palindrome.  Note that 9151 and 999727 are such primes, but I have not checked for larger values.

Comment: @Tony, there are eight primes of the form 99999aba, the smallest is 99999131. There are six primes of the form 9999999aba, the smallest is  9999999151. There are six primes of the form 999999999aba, the smallest is 999999999101. There are nine primes of the form 99999999999aba.

Comment: I assume you are considering any 1-digit number to be a palindrome...

Comment: Yes, one-digit numbers are palindromes.

Comment: @Lucia Consider the modified proposition that for all $b\in \Bbb{Z}^+ : b>1$ every integer greater than 1 is the sum of a number that is a palndrome in base $b$ and a prime.  Is this stronger proposition also "of course" true?

Comment: Freddy Barrera has verified the assertion for every integer up to 10^5.

Comment: You should say somewhere explicitly that by "palindrome" you mean "number whose canonical base-10 expansion is a palindrome".

BTW, I just verified the assertion up to $10^6$.

Comment: And now $10^7$.